# How can I count frequency of 3D plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, histogram

I have list of 3D points (x,y,z) in each vector.

```
matrix[4535x3] = [3,4,2; 3,5,3; 4,5,2; 4,7,6; ...]
```

I would like to count frequency of each 3D point.
For example,

```
[frequency_count] = function([4535x3 3d(x,y,z) points])

[4;        [3,5,4;
 4;         5,4,4;
 6;    <=   2,5,4;
 .          .
 .          .
 . ]        .     ]
```

Is there any functions that can count 3d points in matlab? if not how can I do this?

Comment: Just to make sure it is clear, you want to count the frequency of appearance of each unique row in your matrix? What should be the size of your output? Can you give an example of input/output value that are correct? Can you show what you tried, maybe on a simpler problem?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you can use `unique` with three outputs like this:

```
[unique_points, ia, ic] = unique(matrix, 'rows');
```

Then, use `accumarray` on `ic` like this:

```
frequency_count = accumarray(ic,1);
point_count = [unique_points, frequency_count];
```

Comment: Could you please explain little more on what ia and ic are?

Comment: @BrianLee https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html